# How can I pass a selected value of a GridView to another page using sessions at the same time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, session

First of all, I am a new C# developer and I need some help please, I have a grid view with its SqlDataSource in my aspx file that contains 3 columns ID/Name/Job and several records(rows). When the user selects a row, I would like to redirect to another page and pass as a parameter the value of the selected ID of the row. Users are permitted to select only one row each time. I spent several hours on that however something strange is happened.

I have a method

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       string selectedID;

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = e.Row;
            selectedID = (GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            gvr.Attributes.Add("OnClick","javascript:location.href='Views/EditMenus/EditCompany.aspx?id=" + selectedID + "'");

            gvr.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#FFE6E6'");
            gvr.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''");
            gvr.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");

            Session["IDs"] = selectedID;
     } }
```

In my redirect page I have in page load method the following code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if (Session["IDs"] != null)
        {            
            Label2.Text = "Selected ID is: "+ Session["IDs"].ToString();
         }
    }
```

Now, when I select a row, the redirection to the other page works correctly and the browser url has the correct value of the selected ID according the javascript code above, however the Label2.Text prints a wrong ID. Instead of the value of the selected ID, it prints the value ID of the last row of each page. Why that happens?

It's a bit strange for me since I am using the same variable "selectedID" for both cases as you can see above.

Comment: Why do you store the ID in session , why not just pass as querystring and retrieve the ID on other page?

Comment: Can you try passing `Session["IDs"]` itself through your javascript code.

Comment: since when I am trying that my GridView disappears...

Comment: On your `page_load` try to get the `querystring` value instead of `Session`

Comment: i did that in the pageload Label2.Text = "Selected ID is: " + Request.QueryString["IDs"]; but my GridView disappeared

Comment: It should `Request.QueryString[id]`

Comment: can you give an example of how can I pass Session through javascript code, since I thought that is not possible to assign session values directly through javascript

Comment: `"javascript:location.href='Views/EditMenus/EditCompany.aspx?id=" + Session["IDs"].ToString() + "'"`

Comment: it works but like before, my problem is not how to pass the value to another page, but how to pass the CORRECT value of the selected row to the other page, for example i have the property PageSize = 10 that means 10 rows in a page, when the user selects row four with id="100", the redirect page always prints the id of the last row of each page...

Comment: On the page load how are you trying to retrieve the value?

Comment: if (Session["IDs"] != null){
   Label2.Text = "Selected ID is: "+ Session["IDs"].ToString();

Comment: Please try using `Request.QueryString["id"]` and let me know if it worked

Comment: yesss now it works :))) thank you very much freebird. I confused the Session name ="IDs" with ?id= in the javascript for the url :O) thnx again guys

Comment: Can I ask you another question please? if I wanted to make hidden url, can't I work with Sessions and url using javascript? or it doesn't matter ? sorry if my question is stupid..

Comment: Do you want that the user should not see the id in the url , if so you will have to use Sessions.

Comment: yes exactly, so can I pass my values to another page and at the same time hide to url from the users ?

Comment: So just redirect to the other page using javascript but donot pass id in url and then on other page load just access the Session , this way the user is not aware of the id.

Comment: yes but how can I access the Session since that was not working before Label2.Text = "Selected_id is: " + Session["IDs"];

Comment: Give a try and let me know if it works `Session["IDs"].ToString()`

Comment: no, i just got the value of ID of the last row, not the value ID of the selected row

Comment: Ah so dumb of me I know now why are you getting problems with Session , you are always getting the last value because you are storing id in session in a wrong event .You need to store value in session in SelectedIndexChanged event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sore value of your `ID` in `Session` variable on `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your `GridView`

```
void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
  {

    // Get the currently selected row.
    //Because the SelectedIndexChanging event occurs  before the select operation
    //in the GridView control, the SelectedRow property cannot be used.
    //Instead, use the Rows collection
    //and the NewSelectedIndex property of the 
    //e argument passed to this event handler.

    GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];

    //Cells[0] is for first column so assign according to your column for ID
    Session["IDs"]=row.Cells[0].Text;


  }
```

Comment: oh I see, my question is if 2 differernt event methods can work together properly, since I have GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) and the CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)

Comment: In RowDataBound() method I have the javascript with the redirection as I posted above and in the selctIndexChanging as you mentioned, however it doesn't work together..

Comment: @user1552812 Do a bit of googling for `GridView` `selectedindexchanged` don't use `selectindexchanging` method.